# Does Firebase Unity support Windows UWP or Windows 10 applications?

Tags: windows, firebase, unity-game-engine, uwp

According to Unity documentation, unity supports Windows Applications (UWP) and Windows 10 applications, I just wonder that does the Firebase Unity support Windows Applications (UWP) and Windows 10 applications?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Most Firebase's Unity SDKs are wrappers around their Android and iOS SDKs, so will not work on other platforms.

Some of the Firebase Unity SDKs provide limited support for working on desktop environments, to simplify development and debugging of Android/iOS apps. See the [documentation for a list of features that support this desktop workflow](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#desktop_workflow_implementations_beta_feature_).

As far as I know, none of the Firebase Unity SDKs support running in UWP.

Comment: Thank you very much, Frank

The documentaion here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

says:
Desktop project setup
To use desktop workflow support, you must have an Android or iOS project set up in Firebase console.

Follow the Setup for Android or Setup for iOS instructions to set up the Firebase Unity SDK in your app.
...
It seems only work in the Unity editor, which running on PC (Mac or windows). 
Why it needs GoogleService-Info.plist or google-services.json file?

Comment: Limited support is OK.
But from the documentation, the Firebase Unity does not support Windows application at all. It seems that the limited supported features can work in Unity Editor, not in the Windows Application, which is delivered to client users.

Comment: Could you give me a tutorial for using Firebase Unity in Windows Application? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear: developing on Windows is only supported to simplify developing/debugging of iOS/Android apps. I just clarified that in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

firebase works on windows and mac.
User authentication, real-time database, fire store, and storage are supported.